# Get Values Associated with First Dropdown Chosen

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<select style="width:300px;" id="FirstDD" name="userListingCategory" onchange="FillSelectTwo(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                      <option  disabled="disabled">Category...</option>
                      <?php while($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                      {echo "<option value=". $row['catID'] . ">" .$row['catName']."</option>";}
                    unset($sth2);
            $selectedOptionInCategory = $row['catID'];
                    ?>

                </select> 
                 <select style="width:340px;" id="SecDD" name="userListingSCategory">
                   <option  disabled="disabled">Sub-Category...</option>      
                <?php while($row = $sth3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                      {echo "<option value=". $row['scatID'] . ">" .$row['scatName']."</option>";}
                    unset($sth3);
                 ?>
```

When a 'category' is selected like:
[image: img1]

I want the `subcategories` associated with that first `category` chosen to show up.

I'm running the following SQL:

```
    SELECT scatID, scatName 
FROM Category C, SubCategory SC
WHERE C.catID = SC.catID 
AND C.catID = '$selectedOptionInCategory'
```

**JS:**

```
function FillSelectTwo(id) {  //what is this id for?  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {           
         $('#SecDD').find('option').remove().end().append(data);
        },
        error:function(jxhr){
         console.log(jxhr.responseText);        
        }
    });
}
```

**Problem I get** 
When I test this code out, I selected a `category` like Baby, then the `subcategory` box clears the first 'disabled' option value, but then its an empty set from there and I can't selected any of the values that the `SQL` would return upon selecting a `category`.

What it looks like:
[image: img3]
[image: img4]

Comment: can you add the javascript code

Comment: Additionally, the JS is sitting on the 'index'

Answer (score 0):

javascript ssems to be fine but i doubt if the ajax call is going out in the first place

see in the firebug or developer tools(for chrome) to confirm that the ajax call is made to `index.php`

also remove the options in the success callback so if the ajax fails the `select` remains intact and make an error callback to trace errors

```
 function FillSelectTwo(id) {  //what is this id for?  
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {           
         $('#SecDD').find('option').remove().end().append(data);
        },
        error:function(jxhr){
         console.log(jxhr.responseText);        
        }
    });
}
```

**P.S.** the is a `'` missing at the end of your url may be that is causing the problem

Comment: that is a screen shot not the code `:)` anyway have you checked whether the ajax has called the index.php or not? are you familiar with the firebug?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy...

First you need to make a PHP-function that return the subcats. I often make a ajax.php file. In this I have differents functions that being called on in diffs. $_GET.

The PHP viewer for the result.

```
switch($_GET['ajax'])
{
   case 'subcats' :
   $sql = [YOUR SQL QUERY];
   if(mysql_num_rows($sql)!=0)
   {
    echo "[";
    $i = 0;
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
    {
       if($i!=0)
       {echo ',';}
       echo "['$r[scatID]','$r[ScatName]']";
    }
    echo ']';
   }
   break;
}
```

The jQuery for the ajax request

```
$.post("ajax.php?ajax=subcats",'id='+$("#FirstDD").val(), function(result){
var print = '';
if(result)
{
for(i = 0;i<result.length; i++)
{
  var current = result[i];
  print += '<option value="'+ current[0] +'">'+ current[1] +'</option>';
}
$('#SecDD').html(print);
$('#SecDD').removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

It might be some errors (ondemand writings is not my strongest side ^_^), but try to inteplate this to your script. And comment if you meet any errors...

**

### EDIT

**

But in your case, when I now understand it. In the subcats options element, add the attr. rel, in wich you write the parent id.
Afterwords, you add this jQuery code:

```
$('#FirstDD').change(function(){
var thisId = $(this).attr('id');
$('#SecDD option').addAttr('disabled','disabled');
$('#SecDD option[rel="'+thisId+'"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: This is loading on a user selecting a category first. Not from the URL

Comment: The url when it loads is `index.php`, NOT `ajax.php?ajax=`

Comment: I don't get how that helps since this is a POST request, not a GET.

Comment: But my script is a post see `$.post()`